# How to change the function of 'x' button of a tkinter window ( one in the title bar )?

Tags: python, tkinter

A tkinter window has a title bar with a button 'x' that closes the window when pressed.
Is there any way possible, that does not involve removal of geomertry (such as use of overideredirect()) to change the function related to button 'x'?

Following is a simple window:

```
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()

def en(event):
    l=Label(root,text="name")
    l.grid(row=0)
    e=Entry(root)
    e.grid(row=0,column=1)


frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=250)
frame.bind("<Button-1>",en)
frame.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is your intent just to override the default behavior of the close button (X), e.g. doing cleanup before closing?

Comment: I am having a problem with closing the window. I want to replace root.destroy() with sys.exit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to intercept the `destroy()` call.

```
def exit_function():
    # Put any cleanup here.  
    root.destroy()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', exit_function)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked well. Could you please provide the link of the documentation that you refered to?

Comment: Got this from some old code of mine, don't remember where I got it, probably somewhere on Stackoverflow, usually a good place to look. ;)

Comment: Oh. Thanks Thomas!