# Tkinter Windows doesn't close upon pressing X on the title bar/Alt+F4

Tags: python, tkinter

In Gnome, to change the [default title in the OS bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065527/how-do-i-change-tkinter-default-title-in-os-bar), you have to set the mainWindow. However, when I do that, pressing X on the title bar (or using Alt+F4) no longer closes the entire program. Instead, it shrinks it and leaves behind a blank window. I have to press X again (or Alt+F4 again) to close it completely.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.title("TestWindow")
root.geometry("2000x1000")
root.attributes("-zoomed", True)
mainWindow = tk.Tk(className='TestWindow')

root.mainloop()
```

If I remove the `mainWindow` line, though, the program works as expected, and X closes it completely. Yet calling root.quit() from the program itself will also close it normally.

I've even tried adding `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy())` (and `root.quit()`) to the code, which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624631/how-to-change-the-function-of-x-button-of-a-tkinter-window-one-in-the-title). It didn't work. It still will leave a small window open when I press X/Alt+F4.

What else do I need to do to ensure that the program will close entirely upon pressing X, mirroring calling root.quit() internally?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `Tk()` more than once in a program.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah, such a dumb mistake! Thank you! If you write that up as an answer, I can upvote and accept it.